# Pivot_long with binary variable

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to practice the "tidy" transformation of the data by using pivot_long. Using the movie dataset from the ggplot2movies package. I am curious to know how I can pivot the binary columns into a wide table by creating a new column "genre": something like 
[image]

Here is my code for the first step, I filter all Action and Romance movie out:

```
movies %>%
```

select(title, rating,Action,Romance)%>%
  filter(Action==1|Romance==1)

if I do the following:

```
movies %>% 
select(title, rating,Action,Romance)%>%
filter(Action==1|Romance==1)%>% #select the Action and Romance movies
pivot_longer(names_to = "genre",
             values_to = "Yes/No",
             cols = -title)%>%
```

Comment: I am not getting the data from the package.  What is the correct packagename

Comment: Its the ggplot2movies. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `select` the columns of interest, `filter` where the columns 'Action' or 'Romance' are 1, pivot to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and then `filter` the rows where `Yes/No` column is 1 and remove the `Yes/No`

```
library(ggplot2movies)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
movies %>% 
 select(title, rating,Action,Romance)%>%
 filter(Action==1|Romance==1) %>%
 pivot_longer(cols = Action:Romance, names_to = 'genre', values_to = "Yes/No") %>%
 filter(`Yes/No` == 1) %>%
 select(-`Yes/No`)
```

---

Or instead of reshaping to 'long' format, after the `filter`, step, just `transmute` the columns of interest, and create the 'genre' based on the index of max value of the 'Action', 'Romance' columns per each row

```
nm1 <- c('Action', 'Romance')
movies %>%      
  filter(Action==1|Romance==1) %>% 
  transmute(title, rating, genre = nm1[max.col(.[nm1], "first")])
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
submov <- subset(movies, Action == 1|Romance ==1, 
       select = c(title, rating, Action, Romance))
cbind(submov[c('title', 'rating')], 
     genre = names(submov)[3:4][max.col(submov[3:4], "first")])
```

Comment: Is there a way to only have the "Yes"  title/rating appear while keeping the genre?

Comment: @WYG You meant only 1 values?

Comment: I mean. What I want is three columns: title, genre and rating, if that makes sense.Like what the table movies_sample in the package look .

Comment: @WYG  You can remove the `Yes/No` with `select(-`Yes/No`)

Comment: You mean put it after values_to?

Comment: I also did not get the cols=Action:Romance part, is it saying we are keeping the two columns as rows?

Comment: @WYG It means we are reshaping those columns to long format

Comment: I am not sure what your expected ouptut.  This is based on the one you showed in the expceted

Comment: You can see there are 2 times each title b/c we are keeping both 1 and 0 entries. I was trying to add %>% filter("Y/N")==1) but it returned to error

Comment: @WYG  You can use backquotes for `Y/N`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215903/discussion-between-wy-g-and-akrun).